# Microsoft Speech Recognition Speed

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, sapi

I am working on a small practice app using Microsoft's speech recognizer.  I cannot seem to get it to recognize single words fast enough for what I am doing.  I would like to be able to speak normally and the system will grab "keywords" from what I am saying and produce a string.  Currently I am using a custom grammar of 5 words.  Red, Blue, Yellow, Green, Orange.  For example if I say Red blue yellow.  The engine will grab "Red" and the rest goes into the void.

I have tried using the following:

```
sr.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Single)
```

Then reset it back to single mode after the AudioState changes to "stopped."  This is not fast enough to catch the next word.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried [PauseRecognizerOnRecognition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.pauserecognizeronrecognition.aspx). I looks like this function will buffer your audio input while it is processing the previous audio.

From above MSDN link:

> When PauseRecognizerOnRecognition is true, during the execution of the
>   SpeechRecognized handler the speech recognition service pauses and
>   buffers new audio input as it arrives. Once the SpeechRecognized event
>   handler exits, the speech recognition service resumes recognition and
>   starts processing information from its input buffer.

Comment: In conjunction with RecognizerAudioPosition I was able to get the results I was looking for.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you show how you got this to work? I'm having the same trouble.

Comment: @PhloxMidas  I just pointed him in the right direction he figured out the rest by himself but unfortunately he has not be on SO since he asked the question. The function I pointed him to will buffer the input and judging by his comment he was using RecognizerAudioPosition to set the position in the buffer he was reading from.

Comment: My problem is that PauseRecognizerOnRecognition is only on SpeechRecognizer and not SpeechRecognitionEngine, which I'm using. Furthermore, there's no way to set RecognizerAudioPosition so I can't figure out how he used this. I'll work on it and post an answer if I find one.